# Twitter oauth with flask_oauthlib, Failed to generate request token

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, flask, flask-oauthlib

I tried to use flask_oauthlib to access my twitter api, but all I get is the error : Failed to generate request token. Here is the code.

```
    from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth
    from flask import Flask, url_for, request, jsonify

    app = Flask(__name__)
    oauth = OAuth()

    twitter = oauth.remote_app(
        'twitter',
        base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1/',
        request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
        access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
        authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
        consumer_key='dOJjyxB6gxXWTjdtfPUZcZPjl',
        consumer_secret='im not telling you',
    )


    @app.route('/login')
    def login():
        return twitter.authorize(callback=url_for('authorized',
                                                  next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None))


    @app.route('/authorized')
    @twitter.authorized_handler
    def authorized(resp):
        if resp is None:
            return 'Access denied: error=%s' % (
                request.args['error']
            )
        if 'oauth_token' in resp:
            # session['example_oauth'] = resp
            print(resp)
            return jsonify(resp)
        return str(resp)


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(port=8000, debug=True)
```

This didn't work while using http://term.ie/oauth/example/client.php, I managed to get a request token.

I inspired myself with https://github.com/lepture/example-oauth1-server/blob/master/client.py and http://flask-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html

EDIT

Weird fact : I tried the code here : https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/twitter.py
I didn't changed the key and secret and it worked.

So I tried to change them for my own credentials, and it stopped working. I really can't understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. It appears that the callback URL is mandatory when using flask-oauthlib. So I added a fake one since i'm still on localhost, and it solved this problem.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone found this issue. I'm the author of Flask-OAuthlib. I suggest that you use [Authlib](https://authlib.org/) instead, browser the source code at https://github.com/lepture/authlib. There are many built-in social connections in https://github.com/authlib/loginpass.